# SPFx Command Bar not working after deployment

Tags: spfx, pnp, spfx-extensions, office-dev-pnp

I am working on SPFx Command Bar and everything is working as expected when I do 'gulp serve' and run it in localhost. But when I tried to deploy the same in AppCatalog and installed the same to my site, strangely it does not work.

I tried creating a new default solution and faced the same issue after deployment in site.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Run 'yo @microsoft/SharePoint' and select the default option to create application customizer for command bar.
- Create package with (gulp build, gulp bundle --ship, gulp package-solution --ship)
- Upload the package to the tenant app catalog
- Install the SPFx solution to the site.
- Navigate to the library and select the document
- Command bar should be visible(in my case I am not seeing it)

I would really appreciate if someone can help me here.

Below are the versions I am using

- Node: v10.16.1
- NPM: 6.9.0
- SPFx: 1.8.2

Comment: I got the solution to my own problem. By default, the command bar works with the list and I was testing with library. In order to work with the library, update in sharepoint\assets\elements.xml is required. Updating RegistrationId="100" to RegistrationId="101" fixed the issue.

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question and "accept" your answer so that future searchers with the same issue will see your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the command bar works with the list and I was testing with library. In order to work with the library, update in sharepoint\assets\elements.xml is required. Updating RegistrationId="100" to RegistrationId="101" fixed the issue.